# How to pass/get value checkbox from adapter recycleview to another activity

Tags: java, android

There is something I want to ask, I have recycle view where is pass from adapter to activity, my question is :

I need to get value/data checkbox from adapter viewHolder Recycleview to activity who is use the adapter for show recycleview

CartAdapter.java

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<CartModel> mCartList;
public boolean isSelectedAll = true;

public CartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CartModel> CartList){
    mContext = context;
    mCartList = CartList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.masteritem_cardview_cart, viewGroup, false);
    return new CartViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder cartViewHolder, int i) {
    CartModel currentItem = mCartList.get(i);

    cartViewHolder.mCartCheckbox.setChecked(true); //i want pass this value
```

ShoppingCartActivity.java

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private CartAdapter mCartAdapter;
private ArrayList<CartModel> mCartModelList;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
boolean cartfirst;
private Button mButtonCheckout;

public CheckBox mCartCheckAll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_cart);

    cartfirst = false;

    mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.cart_drawer);
    mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToogle);
    mToogle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_cart);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mCartModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJsonCartItem();

    mButtonCheckout = findViewById(R.id.checkOut_btn);
    mCartCheckAll = findViewById(R.id.cartChecKall_checkBox);

    //firsttime checkall
    mCartCheckAll.setChecked(true);

    mButtonCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShoppingCartActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Confirm Checkout");
            builder.setMessage("Do you really want to Checkout?");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < mCartModelList.size(); i++){
                                     //to here, for checking value if true they will checkout, else do nothing
                                    //checkOutChartJSON();
                                }
                            }

                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShoppingCartActivity.class));
                            finish();   //finish current activity
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                        }});
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });
```

To check validation if checkbox is true they will do function checkOutChartJSON, else do nothing

Comment: You wanna pass the data from adapter to opening a new activity or an existing activity?

Comment: @DPrince not opening, just doing some fuction if click button they pass data from adapter to another activity

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna pass the data or value from an adapter to new activity then you can do it by using Intent and if you wanna pass the value to existing activity then interface is the best way to do it.

For new activity.

```
// Passing data to TargetActivity.class
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("message", str);
startActivity(intent);

// Get the data in TargetActivity.class
Intent intent=getIntent();
String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

For existing activity.

First, make an interface. OnPassingData

```
public interface OnPassingData {
    void onPassing(int value1, String value2,...,int valueN);
}
```

In the adapter.

```
OnPassingData onPassingData;

if (onPassingData != null) {
   onPassingData .onPassing(value1, value2,..,valueN);
}

public void setOnPassingData(OnPassingData onPassingData) {
    this.onPassingData= onPassingData;
}
```

At the adapter calling in activity.

```
adapter.setOnPassingData((value1, value2,...,valueN) -> {

        Log.i(TAG, "value1 : " + value1);
        Log.i(TAG, "value2 : " + value2);
    });
```

Comment: CartAdapter.java and ShoppingCartActivity.java calling each other, i mean CartAdapter is for place where recycleview get data to show it on ShoppingCartActivity, nah after they show data on recycleview, i want get data from recycleview who is already show on ShoppingCartActivity one of them is checkbox, nah how to get data from recycleview/adapter

Comment: You can do it by passing ArrayList in intent. Make your logic to add the selected checkbox value within RecyclerView.